# Ensure that a string is not an sql command

Tags: c#, .net, security, sql-injection

is there something like

```
CheckStringForSql(string);
```

for C#?

I know that I can use parameters, but one of my stored procedures uses sp_executeSQL with a parameter that comes from an xml document. So theoretically anyone can run sql commands, if they know where to put them in.

Any ideas?

Comment: Then this is a ***REALLY*** bad idea.

Comment: I would really really really work around this if at all possible. Limit the amount of sql/parameter as much as you can

Comment: I would approach it the opposite way, what is valid input for that field? Can it have semicolons? The SQL keywords? if not, you can check for those. There is no inbuilt function to my knowledge. Of course, in general this is a bad idea.

Comment: "one of my stored procedures uses sp_executeSQL with a parameter that comes from an xml document." Then rewrite that SP as fast as you can.

Comment: Ok, ok guys. I got it. Bad idea. But this question was not in vain.  BradleyDotNET gave me an idea to keep the sp and don't alow sql injection. See that piece from an xml file has to be in a specific format and then I read about regular expressions. So, thank you Bradley.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to avoid SQL injection is through [parameterized queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180740%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), which actually encode any values that wouldn't fit properly into the SQL context they're being injected into.

Supposing there's a vast bulk of legacy code that you know is vulnerable to SQL injection, you could still try checking for suspicious values on input in another part of your code. For example, by default ASP.NET [tries to prevent](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/xsp/system/Web/CrossSiteScriptingValidation.cs) javascript/HTML injection using a filter on every request.

But this approach is open to false-positives, where you reject perfectly legitimate data because it looks like it was intended to be an injection attack. And it's not nearly as reliable as writing your data-access code with best practices in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

There are thousands of questions on SO on how write secure code that avoids SQL Injection. An insane amount of [blog posts](http://www.enterprisenetworkingplanet.com/netsecur/article.php/3866756/10-Ways-to-Prevent-or-Mitigate-SQL-Injection-Attacks.htm) and even [comics talking about this problem](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Long story short, you can't do this securely. You either need to secure that XML file, or rewrite your code. There is no other way anyone will suggest to you.

Answer (score 0):

StriplingWarrior got it right with the parameterized strings.  But as an extra level of security I think also checking input strings against a white list of characters helps.  You would do that by checking the user input with regular expressions, as such:

```
    public bool validateUserInputAgainstWhiteList(String pword)
    {

        // Gets only a string with letters of any size and any amount of numbers
        var positiveIntRegex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");

        // if pword does not meet regular expression then return false
        if (!positiveIntRegex.IsMatch(pword))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

---

if you go to around the 5:30 minute marker in the following video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8mSImYK3824

it helps demonstrate this.